# WiFi worked during install of Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 but not after install

Tags: networking, broadcom, mate

During the install of Ubuntu-MATE 18.04, I got WiFi working and it downloaded all the things it needed to complete the update.  After re-booting to the installed disk, I can't get WiFi to work.  I go to place to install 3rd party drivers and see the Broadcom driver.  I click it and click install.  It always reverts to no 3rd party drivers and says Broadcom is not working.  If I reboot after that, it isn't there.  Any suggestions?

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1673] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [1028:0200]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: You have a wrong driver installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```